# PHP Quantity Script not working properly

Tags: php, database, cart

Ive looked for the answer. people had the same problem but couldn't find anything useful.

This will update the quantity but leave the wrong number in its place (it'll show correctly if i hit "Update Cart" twice)

and if i have two or more products only the bottom one will update the quantity but it updates all the ones above it to the same quantity in the DB.

```
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id;?>"/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product_title; ?>
                    <!--<img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>">-->
                    </td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='qty' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>"/></td>
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

                        $qty = $_POST['qty'];

                        $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";

                        $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty); 

                        $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

                        $total = $total*$qty;
                    }


                    ?>


                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo "$" . $single_price; ?></td>
                </tr>


            <?php } } ?>

            <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right"><b>Sub Total:</b></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="text-center"><?php echo "$" . $total;?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2"  class="text-center"><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" /></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><button><a href="checkout.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">Checkout</a></button></td>
                </tr>

            </table> 

        </form>

<?php 

function updatecart(){

    global $con; 

    $ip = getIp();

    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

        foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id){

        $delete_product = "delete from cart where p_id='$remove_id' AND ip_add='$ip'";

        $run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_product); 

        if($run_delete){

        echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";

        }

        }

    }
    if(isset($_POST['continue'])){

    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

    }

}
echo @$up_cart = updatecart();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser sends an http request to the server. The server inializes a php instance and this instance processes your (entire) script. The output is sent back to the browser and the php instance is "terminated". Now your browser redenders the output and client-side stuff "happens".
When you press the button/link to change the quantity the cycle starts again The browser sends a http request (with some POST data) and the php script is executed.
In this case your script first sends the output for displaying the *old* values and then updates those values. You have to change that sequence. First process the POST data then display the current values.